# QPainterPath and cubicTo, smooth Line

Tags: qt, qt4, qpainter

I am Trying to Connect points by smooth line as shown in Image.

How can i get smooth lines as shown in image?

```
QPainterPath myPath(A);
myPath.cubicTo(A,A,B);
myPaht.cubicTo(B,B,C);
myPath.cubicTo(C,C,D);
myPainter.drawPath(myPath);
```

Image:- http://postimg.org/image/44vh9m2ur/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this code and I got similar result

```
QPainterPath myPath(QPointF(50,50));//start point
myPath.cubicTo(60,25,80,80,90,60);  //set another points

scene->addPath(myPath,QPen(Qt::red));//I use graphicsscene, but you can use, what you want
ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
ui->graphicsView->show();
```

Comment: Thanks for your Reply. How can I draw similar smooth path for more than 4 points? About 100 points. Using two QPainterPath.cubicTo (starting next One from previous one's End) does not create smooth line. Any Comment on creating clipping rect/region for black boxes in Image attached?